# Rails 3 and Google maps api v3 incompatibilities

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a **rails 3.1** application with this simple code in the home page (rhtml file),

- If I run the same code in a html file it works.
- If I run this in my rails app it doesn't **and** I do not get any kind of errors using firebug.

Also: I have jquery-rails gem.
What could be the problem?

```
     <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
     </script>

     <script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        init();
     });
     </script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
      function init() {
         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
         var myOptions = {
         zoom: 8,
         center: latlng,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
       };
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
      }
     </script>
```

then I have my div:

```
    <div id="home">
      <div style="width:100%;height:400px" id="map_canvas"></div>
    </div>
```

with this css:

```
 #home #map_canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;       
 }
```

Comment: Other information:
I see the map just a a moment and then it disappears.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like some other JS and/or CSS that's conflicting.

PS: not sure why you're specifing the style width and height both inline and in a CSS declaration.  Only need one of them, although no harm in duplicating.

Comment: Duncan is right, I think.  What is happening is that another div is covering it due to CSS (that's why you see it appear and then vanish).  Try without any CSS at all by removing #map_canvas from the CSS file temporarily to pinpoint the issue and do an Inspect Element/view source to see if the map area shows up in your code (it should).

Comment: Thanks, but the behaviour does not change (I tried removing the CSS **at all**). Could rails do something wrong?

Comment: So when you *disable* CSS, do you see the map or does it flicker then disappear?

Comment: The problem was not about CSS I think, I disabled CSS but no map appeared. I was using rails3.1 with assets enabled, when I disabled them the map stop generating problems.
Thanks anyway.